# How to spot public S3 buckets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, cloud-security

I'm trying to list all the buckets with some kind of public access in an account.

The question is: **is my rationale correct?**

1. I first checked buckets' **access block configuration**:

```
filtered_buckets = list(filter(lambda item: not list_in_list(exceptions, item['Name']), buckets))
public_buckets = []
public_acl_indicator = ['http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers','http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers']
permissions_to_check = ['READ', 'WRITE']

def check_bucket_access_block():
    for bucket in filtered_buckets:
        try:
            response = s3client.get_public_access_block(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
            for key, value in response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration'].items():
                logger.info('Bucket: {}, {}: {}'.format(bucket['Name'], key, value))
                if not response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicAcls'] and not response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicPolicy'] and bucket['Name'] not in public_buckets:
                    public_buckets.append(bucket['Name'])
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchPublicAccessBlockConfiguration':
                logger.info("Bucket: {} has no Public Access Block Configuration".format(bucket['Name']))
            else:
                logger.info("unexpected error: %s" % (e.response))
```

If any bucket is set to False on both BlockPublicAcls and BlockPublicPolicy, then it IS public. No matter how they configured on Policies and ACLs(**correct?**).

2. Then, I proceed to check the buckets' **policy status**:

```
 def check_bucket_status():
    try:
        for bucket in filtered_buckets:
            response = s3client.get_bucket_policy_status(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['PolicyStatus']['IsPublic']
            logger.info('Bucket Name: {}, Public: {}'.format(bucket['Name'], response))
            if response == True and bucket['Name'] not in public_buckets:
                public_buckets.append(bucket['Name'])
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        logger.info("unexpected error: %s" % (e.response))
```

If a bucket returns true for isPublic, then it IS public. No matter the previous function result.

3. In the last step, I check the buckets **ACLs** for **AllUser** and **AuthenticadedUsers** permissions:

```
def check_bucket_acl():
    for bucket in filtered_buckets:
        try:
            response = s3client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
            logger.info('Bucket: {}, ACL: {}'.format(bucket['Name'], response['Grants']))
            for grant in response['Grants']:
                for (key, value) in grant.items():
                    if key == 'Permission' and any(permission in value for permission in permissions_to_check):
                        for (grantee_key, grantee_value) in grant['Grantee'].items():
                            if 'URI' in grantee_key and grant['Grantee']['URI'] in public_acl_indicator:
                                if bucket['Name'] not in public_buckets:
                                    public_buckets.append(bucket['Name'])
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            logger.info("unexpected error: %s" % (e.response))
```

When I print the full result, it outputs some buckets. All of them were caught in the first step:

```
check_bucket_access_block()
logger.info('\n')
check_bucket_status()
logger.info('\n')
check_bucket_acl()
logger.info('\n')
logger.info('Public Buckets: {}'.format(public_buckets))
```

Another question: Is it **necessary** to check the Objects' ACLs after going through all these steps? If yes, **why**?

Comment: It is not a direct answer for the question but you can enable AWS Macie, and this service can list the public buckets as well.

Answer (score 1):

> If any bucket is set to False on both BlockPublicAcls and
> BlockPublicPolicy, then it IS public. No matter how they configured on
> Policies and ACLs(correct?).

No that's not correct at all. It just means that the bucket is allowed to have a public Policy/ACL, it doesn't mean that the bucket actually has a public Policy/ACL.